# AtCoder Beginner Contest 062　C問題で不正解が発生する

Tags: python, python3

## 問題文

> 縦 Hブロック、横 W ブロックの板チョコがあります。 すぬけ君は、この板チョコをちょうど 3 つのピースに分割しようとしています。
>   ただし、各ピースはブロックの境目に沿った長方形でなければなりません。 すぬけ君は、3 つのピースの面積 (ブロック数)
>   をできるだけ均等にしようとしています。  具体的には、3 つのピースの面積の最大値を Smax、最小値を Smin
>   としたとき、Smax−Smin を最小化しようとしています。  Smax−Smin の最小値を求めてください。

https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc062/tasks/arc074_a

## 回答方針

以下の方針でアプローチを行いました。

### 縦か横の長さが３の倍数

答えは０に決定する。

### 縦か横のどちらかが偶数の場合

奇数の方の長さの切断場所を総当りで求める。
偶数側の辺は２等分する。
これで長方形は３等分されるので、最も差の少ない答えを計算する。

### 縦・横のどちらも奇数の場合

はじめの切断場所を総当りで求める。
二度目の切断は可能な限り真ん中で行う。(奇数辺なので真ん中は不可能)
３等分された長方形の最も差の少ない答えを計算する。

## 疑問点

例題のテストケースでは全て正解するのですが、
実際にジャッジにかけると２件の不正解が出ます。

なぜ不正解がでるのでしょうか？
自身では疑問が解決できなかったため、ここで質問させて頂きます。

## ジャッジにかけたソースコード

```py
H, W = list(map(int, input().split()))

ans = float('inf')

# 縦と横どちらかが偶数である場合を考える
# 縦の長さが偶数の場合
if H % 2 == 0:
  # 横から切断
  for x in range(1, W):
    S1 = x * H
    S2 = (W - x) * (H / 2)
    ans = min(ans, abs(S1 - S2))
# 縦の長さが偶数の場合
if W % 2 == 0:
  # 縦から切断
  for x in range(1, H):
    S1 = W * x
    S2 = (H - x) * (W / 2)
    ans = min(ans, abs(S1 - S2))
# 縦と横の両方の長さが奇数だった場合
else:
  # 横から切断
  for x in range(1, W):
    S1 = x * H
    S2 = (H // 2) * (W - x)
    S3 = ((H // 2) + 1) * (W - x)
    # 縦横療法が奇数だった場合３種類の面積が出現するので、大小関係を計算する必要が出てくる。
    S_max = max(S1, S3)
    S_min = min(S1, S2)
    ans = min(ans, S_max - S_min)
  # 縦から切断
  for x in range(1, H):
    S1 = W * x
    S2 = (W // 2) * (H - x)
    S3 = ((W // 2) + 1) * (H - x)
    S_max = max(S1, S3)
    S_min = min(S1, S2)
    ans = min(ans, S_max - S_min)

# 縦か横が３等分できるなら、答えは０になる。
if H % 3 == 0 or W % 3 == 0:
  ans = 0

print(int(ans))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者さんのコードだとH=100000, W=5という入力に対して50000を返しますが、実際には横方向に33333,33333,33334と切るとより良い5という値が得られます。

より単純に、縦横問わず１つ目の切れ目の入れ方を全列挙し、一方の切れ端をなるべく半分ずつになるように切る、というのが良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

まず、解説と、自分のコードの違いを洗い出しましょう。

解説にある4パターンを、すべて調べるコードに、なっているか？。

縦の三分割と、横の三分割の、バリエーションを試してないのがわかります。